# How can the fit parameters (and expression) be extracted from vega regressions?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

**Context**
Following the [docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/regression.html), it is possible to add a regression line to a vega plot i.e.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "url": "data/movies.json"
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "filled": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "IMDB Rating",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "firebrick"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "IMDB Rating",
          "on": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "IMDB Rating",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "IMDB Rating",
          "on": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
          "params": true
        },
        {"calculate": "'R²: '+format(datum.rSquared, '.2f')", "as": "R2"}
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "color": "firebrick",
        "x": "width",
        "align": "right",
        "y": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"type": "nominal", "field": "R2"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Question**
Here, the R^2 value is exposed through 'datum.rSquared' but how can I access the fitting parameters and other related information?

I couldn't find this in the documentation or elsewhere and now that vega has upped its security I couldn't work out how to access the 'keys' of 'datum' using some kind of javascript. Any information would be much appreciated and bonus points if someone can suggest a good debugging practice for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation for the Vega Regression transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/regression/), the options **"params"** and **"as"** can be specified for Vega to output parameters and coordinates to plot the regrssion lines:

> **"params"**: A boolean flag indicating if the transform should return the
> fit model parameters (one object per group), rather than trend line
> points. The resulting objects include a coef array of fitted
> coefficient values (starting with the intercept term and then
> including terms of increasing order) and an rSquared value (indicating
> the total variance explained by the model).
>
> **"as"**: The output fields for the predictor and predicted values for the
> line of best fit. If unspecified, the x and y parameter field names
> will be used.

Using the [Vega example for regression](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/regression/), here is a working example of how to get coefficients and R-squared values.

Apparantly Vega will output either "params" or "as" in a regression transform -- but not both. As a workaround, we can get the coefficients and R-squared by adding another dataset (**"trend_params"**) that is a duplicate of **"trend"**, but with the property ***"params": true***.

The Vega online editor's tab "DATA VIEWER" shows data fields and data values for each dataset. The "trend" dataset has values to plot the regession line(s), whereas "trend_params" has fields ***coef*** (array of coefficients) and ***rSquared***.

For linear regression of all data points, the y-intercept of the fitted line can be accessed in dataset "trend_params" by signal expression **datum.coef[0]** or **datum['coef'][0]** and the slope of the line by signal expression **`datum['coef'][1]`**

Try the differnt options for regression models and grouping, and observe the plotted chart and also the data in datasets "trend" and "trend_params".

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAE0JNjiLtOADZtM2gO50Y2zIrjjZ2kzXFxtUJCagMT+uGdiGiRtBghDAFooCQAzGjIGRSQmEw8HMgcICHVtBDh6NlkISmkQHCRZWTcyNAEZa1l6OoAGFpl4BKxW9pAkBkw2HIAvODRyyrKcsnFvCDQAbVBZ-PH8wtky4m8GMfRXdyRFMqY3TdRQNxwB8Yi0qEwytlV1edQFkAO4I7KzWpk4AAPHBlHBsSxlACODEmMjBJgAniAALoAX1RUmWSFW6HhCIA8op5McZNsTLs0ABmGSnJxoS7ia6PdDJcRkMYyBBuNAARk5SEBVJkEEwcBBqB56MxIBWexAmTYDBwTCRpJ2cvEEg5IFp5wZTNucHujxkzzUEjeH017jK7PEDhR6ORMlk+hQ7yxOJACDYwQUZSSJnGrsw-B9fpKogkZXsSHEEFibEUCEWoEwCJwcviJlFJJAQJwx3QIYYCAWAHIAErmUXibQAFTYyEGCm0lf0NXLyO0AEIALzacR+EzaABko+0JbL5YAkgBZAAiACE2x22V3ewOhyYg6i0dLZeN7I5NsLFYooHLwzR-TJY-HE8nUyB05nxhksjlozIFUqVc-plmIN0F-ZUEW0PtIO0cs7QccttAAfmguckGEJNtAAcUcODtFQaDEzYcsQD3TkChgIp6RAQDvDWMiKIxEAk2JSjqOA8o2ERQlmIYoFa2ZUBWODJskDcAAKctAXLABKYiZEFdBqwMOtG2bNhW3bNQ2TKJF0HnZdV00-4+ktEAGC2R1909OVjycAB9CpkgQeYzySS81l9G9nJfVkEyTFMPRfDM5Q-BQv0kH9FEVMCAISIDxlAlUIKgmDsLgeCkPLFC0KMLD7TS3D8LYQjiOdb06L1KjYpo9B1nIzYGKYwwWKqti8S4pqeMBPjmpmaq5GEsSJOk2SQHkkBFNrBthJbCADJqbTxj0lcNPmuEjmxN57F2PcSKorw0ktKzxkFO8gvGL4fhdAaNFAEN3W9DzbxAeIjXOcaa0cKbVPUtdagY1l2XGRpmgxI70FVQK332NxvjzWRrsou73IjMoXpMN6lrmrT-rjQH0E6Mhul2gV-QCtRMDScYJs+lT9DU2aVq001lEcZkdRrJspn2uUTvlZRzi2uA7xoKAAGsAGFFXEZkBFBl86Ep3TF2W36nhZ6XzrgWITT27w5QhzIaAFxRdmFsXJYYDXUFl0rkEUUXDshuUIARBAmA41HIv8263WRzyRscGJ5Eo1mmouUaWO547UZvdGqY+5TpvprG-pkHSBKj8GY9exblZTkbsxMfEKigOh05AMkKVQFpKFl4UaFGSjK72HkADZ0SlNMzpAyKlU9znw9iJBL34uRffQGzTxlbE5V8RRSFtXvovQLL0Nyh0pW9I4HefV85S+fvvbH0NxjnheePEIO9lAUOi1AeSM716OZDRt6zIY8u9EVkAIdf8ZiBGiKSKotr4V3VOMeIDgmDKDFsRDu0o95Hl4ofRG49vInnsutJyAdL5FFAUqEMoDRRdR6nFdAFZKzkE-LkWqRQ8LwQANR5HKlIaClByysPLBhJe2gVT0O0EwhKCJOHsM4ZLLW8RS6s3wNBVhU4KwxC1l2BYLRnSTn0KWBRalYjKJ5Go+R5ZFE6ORAsAATPojR04jHKMpGo8sojoKVkiBAaERxAj8KYQYxQABlVxDhZAbmRCNB+YDyR7FMQIFoH8m7gNQJSNoDFC4xLCeMVIw9RYFxoDuYuw8y7JKrpKF+EhMDeIbqA5uvJ24dzRGiIAA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A scatter plot with trend line calculated via user-configurable regression methods.",
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "autosize": "pad",

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "method", "value": "linear",
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": [
        "linear", "log", "exp", "pow", "quad", "poly"
      ]}
    },
    {
      "name": "polyOrder", "value": 3,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 3, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "groupby", "value": "none",
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["none", "genre"]}
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "movies",
      "url": "data/movies.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum['Rotten Tomatoes Rating'] != null && datum['IMDB Rating'] != null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "trend",
      "source": "movies",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "regression",
          "groupby": [{"signal": "groupby === 'genre' ? 'Major Genre' : 'foo'"}],
          "method": {"signal": "method"},
          "order": {"signal": "polyOrder"},
          "extent": {"signal": "domain('x')"},
          "x": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
          "y": "IMDB Rating",
          "as": ["u", "v"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "trend_params",
      "source": "movies",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "regression",
          "groupby": [{"signal": "groupby === 'genre' ? 'Major Genre' : 'foo'"}],
          "method": {"signal": "method"},
          "order": {"signal": "polyOrder"},
          "extent": {"signal": "domain('x')"},
          "x": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
          "y": "IMDB Rating",
          "params": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "movies", "field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating"},
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "movies", "field": "IMDB Rating"},
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {
      "title": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating",
      "orient": "bottom", 
      "scale": "x",
      "grid": true, 
      "tickCount": 5
    },
    {
      "title": "IMDB Rating",
      "orient": "left", 
      "scale": "y",
      "grid": true, 
      "tickCount": 5
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "movies"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "IMDB Rating"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5},
          "size": {"value": 16}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "data": "trend",
          "name": "curve",
          "groupby": "Major Genre"
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "line",
          "from": {"data": "curve"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "u"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "v"},
              "stroke": {"value": "firebrick"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "from": {"data": "trend_params"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "text": {"signal": "['Regression method: ' + method, '.', 'Group by: ' + groupby, '.', 'Coefficients: ', datum['coef'][0], datum['coef'][1], datum['coef'][2], datum['coef'][3], '.', 'R-squared: ' + datum['rSquared'] ]" },
              "x": {"value": 250},
              "y": {"value": 300},
              "fill": {"value": "black"},
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 1.0},
              "fontSize": {"value": 16}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Just to summarize, the key 'coef' was the missing information and finding this key seems to have been done by using the DATA VIEWER tab.